# MIME-Email Images appear as tappable boxes on iphone

Tags: html, ios, html-email, email-attachments, mime

Ok, so I have an HTML email with several inline images (charts and such). The images are embedded using CID. The email works perfectly fine on all desktop platforms. My issue is that the images are no longer inline when you try to open the email on iPhone (IOS mail app or IOS Outlook).

This is what they look like on IOS mail:

[image]

And this is what happens when you tap one of those boxes:

[image]

(contents of the image are irrelevant)

So, they load fine if you tap them individually, but I really need them to appear inline. Any idea whats going on? I thought maybe the images were too large, but one of the images is only 12kb and it still doesn't appear. In total the email is only about 850kb, which really shouldn't be too big either.

A few things to note:

- It is definitely sending properly as an HTML email, as all of the CSS in the titles and the HTML tables (not shown) are working perfectly.
- There is no "Download all images" link at the bottom of the email, as many of the suggestions I have found online seem to say.
- I have "Download remote images" enabled in my settings.
- All of the images are .png

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. For whatever reason this happens when I am making an absolute reference i.e. (C:\ReportEmail\Data\Logo.png) to the file path in my code. If I put the images in the same folder as the script and make a relative reference to the working directory  i.e.(.\Logo.png) it works fine. I have no idea why this is the case, as the two types of references should be pretty much identical in usage. Oh well.